# Camel Java-DSL: Using header in to()

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I'm trying to setup my routes and have the problem, that a processor had to choose the 'next working queue'. He did this and wrote it to the header.

Now I would like to use it in my route:

```
...
.bean(MyProcessor.class, "doSomething") //
.to("${headers.NEXT_QUEUE}") //
.log("Finished");
...
from(...)....
```

Is there a way to do this.

Is this even possible, as the RouteBuilder has to work here with a 'placeholder'?

Sry, I'm new to Camel.

Comment: Me, idiot.... I think I should use 'when'.... I will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

See this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

You need to use the recipient list EIP pattern for dynamic to.